# Im trying to wait for a user's response in dm's. Then once the user has replied the bot will continue sending messages

Tags: discord.py

```py
@client.command()
async def order(ctx):
await ctx.reply("Check your dm's")
await ctx.author.send("hi")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [wait for message from same author in dm discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65362288/wait-for-message-from-same-author-in-dm-discord-py)

Comment: Use `wait_for` and check for dm channel.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by `continue sending messages`. Does the bot send message privately to you or what?

Answer (score 0):

Use `@client.event`, for example

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
      if message.content.startswith("Hi"):
         await message.author.send("Hello, How i can help u?")
```